# Why were the fuses not protecting the circuit?

Tags: short-circuit, fuses

I bought a Aprilia SR 50 Scooter with a "small" problem, the frontlight and the horn are not working, because the 10A fuse does blow up if the key is turned...

I don't know what happened today, but I installed a new battery (which had 12,6V), then after I turned the keys to position "On" the fuseholder started to heat up and the plastic on the fuses melted, but both fuses stayed alive!! There was also a little bit smoke coming from the rear. I turned the key to position off immediately. The circuit was damaged and not protected by the fuses. I used the right fuses on the right place as shown in the circuit (10A and 15A), a few parts broke. My break light broke and the scooter is not making any noise when trying to turn it on, the starter seems to be broken now.

I am lucky that I had all front parts including cockpit disconected (except the ignition), only the rear of the scooter was connected to the circuit.

Is it possible that this happened because most of the electrical consumers were disconnected and thus the whole current was too strong for the small number of remaining consumers?

Or maybe because the ECU was laying on the floor, im not sure if it is allowed to put electrical parts on the floor.

Why were the fuses not blowing up and protect the circuit? And do I have to throw my scooter away now, or can I still fix it?

[This is the circuit](https://www.aprilia.at/assets/fileupload/modelle/downloads/SR50.pdf):

[image: Aprilia SR50]

```
LEGEND FOR SWITCH PANEL - SR 50 PUREJET
1) multiple plug
2) dipped beam / high beam relay
3) Oil level switch
4) Fuel level sensor
5) Cockpit (matrix)
6) Immobilizer antenna
7) Ignition key switch
8) Horn
9) Left light switch
10) Rear brake light switch (on left
Switch)
11) Right light switch
12) Front brake light switch (on
right switch)
13) Rear turn signal, left
14) Tail light
15) Double light bulb for stand
/ Brake light
16) Rear turn signal, right
17) License plate lighting (only at
Versions USA / CH)
18) Pick up
19) generator
20) Voltage regulator
21) injection relay
22) Starting relay (fault protection)
23) starter motor
24) Battery
25) fuses
26) Fuel pump
27) Air nozzle
28) Fuel Injector
29) Pressure sensor (or in the control unit
integrated)
30) Cylinder head temperature switch
31) HS coil
32) spark plug
33) Gas control sensor
34) Serial connection (Diag.) 35) Oil pump
36) ECU control unit
37) Speed ​​sensor
38) Front turn signal, right
39) Front parking lights (only at
Versions USA / CH)
40) low beam
41) high beam
42) Front turn signal, left
43) headlights
44) diode
45) -
46) -
47) -
48) -
49) -
CABLE COLORS
Ar Orange
Az light blue
B blue
Bi white
G yellow
Gr Gray
M brown
N black
R red
V green
Vi Viola
Ro Rosa
```

Comment: my guess is that you were drawing less than 15A of current .... 15A x 12V = 180W .... that is still enough power to heat up components .... you probably have a short-circuit somewhere

Comment: `do I have to throw my scooter away now, or can I still fix it?` .... it is not possible to answer such a question because it depends on your skill level, which is unknown

Comment: `most of the electrical consumers were disconnected and thus the whole current was too strong for the small number of remaining consumers`   ..... please google `ohm's law` and learn the relationship between voltage, resistance and current

Comment: @jsotola, if you unplug the rear blinkers then the front blinkers are way faster, because there is more current flowing through, so if I unplugg all components but one, then there is way less resistance and all the current is flowing through this one, isn't it?

PS: I solved the problem btw, there was a short circuit at the rear lights

Comment: did you ever bother to check the voltage before and after unplugging components?  ..... as you unplug components, the total resistance increases ..... you are totally wrong in your thinking about the current flowing through one component ..... you really need  to learn about `ohm's law`

Comment: @jsotola, but if I have three lamps with lets say 20 ohm each, then they have 60 ohm together. If I unplug two, then there is only 20 ohm left, so I don't understand how the resistance increases, it decreases...

Comment: how  are the lamps connected together?

Comment: @jsotola, take a look at the circuit plan in my post

Comment: let  me rephrase that ...... think about how the lamps are connected together  .... hint: you are wrong about the resistance being 60 ohms when three lamps are connected

Comment: @jsotola, oh I see my mistake. It behaves differently in a series connection and in parallel connection.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing faults is possible only with hands on the faulty system. Your machine can even have a poor earlier repair or modification attempts which have changed the circuit to something else than your diagram or there's damaged wires, connectors or other parts. Get local pro help. We can only make guesses.

Comment: But how is it possible that the fuses did not break but were melting instead and stayed alive? Isn't it the purpose of fuses to melt if the current is too high? There was a short circuit at the breaks btw.

Comment: You have not a massive  overcurrent, only a little. Fuse can stand it a long time and get hot. Bad fuse make it worse. Loose fuse holder is a fire maker like any loose contacs.